# Some lights not showing in Eevee?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I copy pasted some lights around the scene, the strange thing is, some of them don't show up in preview or render. it's very random because some lights in the background will show but some in the foreground wouldn't. for example, the light selected in the 2nd pic and several area lights. Can someone help?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach more screenshots? And please spot out the disappearing light. It is not clear which light is missing.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded another screenshot. I don't know if the problem is I added too many lights or something

Comment: How many lights do you have in your scene? Eevee has a limit of 128 active lights (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html)

Comment: if Blunder's answer doesn't help...please provide blend file